# python regex ignoring underscore incorrectly

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to grab filenames from a list of endings that looks like this:

```
final count: {'.pem': 5027, '__base__': 434, '.rb': 62341, '/AUTHORS': 1358, '.sty': 859, '.gitignore': 193,...}
```

My regex looks as follows:

```
p = re.compile(r"'([\W]+)(.*?)'")
```

It works ok except on `'__base__'`, where I get `'__base__'` instead of the 'base' I want due to underscores being a word-like character. I tried:

```
p = re.compile(r"'([\W]+|\_+)(.*?)'")
p = re.compile(r"'([\W]+|_+)(.*?)'")
```

and

```
p = re.compile(r"'([\W]+)|(_+)(.*?)'")
```

but none worked. What is the proper way to do this? Thank you

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Hi Julien, my goal is to take a linecount of all files by type in a dir (did that), now I want it pretty as in alphabetized like:

`'__underscorefile__': 23, '.a': 343, 'Procfile': 32, '.xhtml': 983`

Once I alphabetize the list as nothing but words (except `__underscorefile__`)  I want to go back in and grab the linecount values from my initial file which looks like the "final count" in the original question

Comment: guess I should grab to values as I iterate in the alphabetize function and make the file piece by piece, but that's my goal. It'll be a reusable script to count lines by filetype for large projects, yall are welcome to it if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_{0,2}':", my_str)
```

It will capture only consecutive letters and numbers before 0 to 2 `_`, and `':`, since you only need the string before `':`.

**Explanation**:
`{0,2}` matches 0 to 2 of the previous.
`[a-zA-Z0-9]+` is used instead of `\w+` since the latter would match `_` as well.

Comment: yes, now if I have `__base__`, `base__`, or `__base`, my group(1) always grabs base. Both answers were helpful, thank you guys I forgot about {m,n}

Answer (score 2):

Try adding in the carat to make an exception to your regex

```
p = re.compile(r"'([\W^_]+)(.*?)'")
```

When `^` is *outside* of a matching group (the square brackets) it means at the beginning of a string or beginning of a new line. When it is *inside* the matching group, it means "negates" or "not".

Comment: thank you. What does the carat do here? from what I see, within a [ ], ^ normally means all characters except whatever, if it's at the beginning. I don't see anything about it being in the middle

Comment: @codyc4321 i edited my answer. Hopefully that clears a bit up!

Comment: thank you James...it probably should clear it up, but I'm still confused. I just did:

`([\W^_]+)(.*)` in pythex checking for `__base` and it got it all, with groups `__` and 'base'. but if it means 'not', it would read as "one or more non-word characters, not underscore", but the regex correctly matches the underscore. What does the not negate?

Answer (score 1):

```
p = re.compile(r"'([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*?)'")
```

You can simply use this .